# Performance Issue between List and Map in C++

Tags: c++, performance, list, dictionary

Which is faster, an integer comparison or a search in a map with the `contains()` function ?

Comment: `myString > 0 && myString <= myStringList.size()`...this is the actuall code?

Comment: What types are `myStringList` and `myMap`?

Comment: These don't look like standard STL string or map objects. What is `isEmpty()` and `contains()`? Difficult to guess at what the efficiency problem might be if it's not a standard implementation of STL. Also, why are you comparing what appears to be a string to an int?

Comment: Impossible to draw a meaningful conclusion without more information.

Comment: @UmNyobe: Looking at `myString.isEmpty()` I would fear it is, assuming that the <= size comparison totally does nothing useful.

Comment: The second if statement doesn't make sense logically ...is there even a > operator for string which compares string with a integer..same thing with <= operator...

Comment: @Xaltar, it's still not clear, I doubt that code even compiles. Try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes contains has to check every entry against your string, size just gets the amount of elements in the map, without having to do a lot of comparison code. it is worth reading up more on STL containers since a map and list are very different in storing and accessing data speeds. (list needs traversing, map has direct access for example).

Comment: Yeah, THAT was useful. Thanks !